# How to find commands addresses?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, instructions, emu8086

I am a beginner in assembly programming and I experience some issues with this problem. So the addresses of the commands below are defined by the contents of `CS:IP` registers . If `CS` is equal to 0750h and `IP` is 047Bh find all the addresses of the commands. It's given that all the commands have a size of 3 bytes.

I have found that address is equal to **segment * 10h + offset**. That means 0750h * 10h + 047Bh = 797Bh. After that in order to find the address of each command I just add 3 to 797Bh? Am I right?

```
start:

mov ax, data
mov ds, ax

mov al,3Fh
mov ah,30h
cmp al,ah  

jl p1

add ah,al
sub ah,30h   

p1:
add al,ah
sub al,30h

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h    
ends
```

Comment: Yes that should be fine.

Comment: @Jester even if I have jump 3 bytes are added to 797B?

Comment: Just for terminology sake, they are referred to as *instructions*, not *commands*. The collection of instructions supported by a given CPU is referred to as the *instruction set* for that CPU. Each instruction is translated by an assembler into *machine language* which is one or more bytes that the CPU actually interprets in memory and that the IP points to for fetching and executing. The number of bytes needed by each instruction depend upon the instruction and type of arguments that instruction has. This is documented in an instruction set reference manual for the CPU.

Comment: *It's given that all the commands have a size of 3 bytes.* I don't think that's true for all of the instructions in the code you show. For example, `add al,ah` is a 2 byte instruction. See starting at page 26 in this sheet: [Intel 8086 Microprocessor Data Sheet](https://www.archive.ece.cmu.edu/~ece740/f11/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:8086-datasheet.pdf)

Comment: @lurker really thanks for your reply , appreciate it .

Comment: @lurker, in fact, all of the instructions are 2-byte instructions, except the two `mov ax` instructions, which are 3 bytes.

Comment: @prl The `sub ah, 30h` instruction is also a 3-byte instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's given that all the commands have a size of 3 bytes

This is certainly false. Look below to find out.

`CS:IP = 0750h:047Bh` corresponds to linear address 0000797Bh.

```
0000797B mov ax, data   3 bytes : opc + word immediate
0000797E mov ds, ax     2 bytes : opc + modr/m

00007980 mov al, 3Fh    2 bytes : opc + byte immediate
00007982 mov ah, 30h    2 bytes : opc + byte immediate
00007984 cmp al, ah     2 bytes : opc + modr/m

00007986 jl  p1         2 bytes : opc + byte displacement

00007988 add ah, al     2 bytes : opc + modr/m
0000798A sub ah, 30h    3 bytes : opc + modr/m + byte immediate

         p1:
0000798D add al, ah     2 bytes : opc + modr/m
0000798F sub al, 30h    2 bytes : opc + byte immediate

00007991 mov ax, 4c00h  3 bytes : opc + word immediate
00007994 int 21h        2 bytes : opc + byte immediate
```